# How do I arrive at the integral representation of Catalan Numbers using Mellin Transform

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers, mellin-transform

I have been trying to understand how to obtain the integral representation of the Catalan numbers using Mellin transformations and get stuck when I obtain the inverse Mellin transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The Catalan numbers have the following integral representation (see [Catalan Number Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Properties)):

---

$$C_n=\int_0^4 \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}\ x^n\,dx=\frac{4^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\ \Gamma(n+2)}\tag{1}$$

Comment: I am curious as to how you arrive at the integral though, using Mellin transformations

Comment: @Luke The Mellin transform of $fx)$ is $\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\ x^{s-1}\,dx$. Set $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{4-x}{x}}\ (1-\theta(x-4))$ and evaluate the Mellin transform at $s=n+1$.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but is there a reason we set f(x) to be that?

Comment: I am reading a paper that uses the result on the R.H.S of (1) and find the function f(x) using Mellin transformations. This is the first time I am looking at these transformation so I am in the deep end

Comment: @Luke The integral in formula (1) in the answer above is evaluated from $0$ to $4$, whereas the Mellin transform integral is evaluated from $0$ to $\infty$. The function $(1-\theta(x-4))$ evaluates to $0$ for $x>4$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Comment: Is it allowed for me to link a paper, because I think this Heaviside step function is the key to understanding, but I am unsure

Comment: @Luke I used the integral representation at the link in the answer above. One can also evaluate the inverse Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_n^{-1}\left[\frac{4^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\ \Gamma(n+2)}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\sqrt{x (4-x)}\ (1-\theta(x-4))$ in which case $C_n$ can be derived from the Mellin transform $C_n=\mathcal{M}_x\left[\frac{1}{2 \pi}\sqrt{x (4-x)}\ (1-\theta(x-4))\right](n)=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{1}{2 \pi}\sqrt{x (4-x)}\ (1-\theta(x-4))\ x^{n-1}\,dx=\frac{4^n\ \Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\ \Gamma(n+2)}$.

Comment: @Luke I used Mathematica to generate the result, but I also told Mathematica to simplify it based on the assumptions $x>0$. You can use WolframAlpha to generate the same result (see Alternate form assuming x is positive: at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseMellinTransform%5B++4%5En+Gamma%5B1%2F2+%2B+n%5D%2F%28Sqrt%5BPi%5D+Gamma%5B2+%2B+n%5D%29%2C+n%2C+x%5D).

Comment: Thank you, it's just that I am trying to prove the result from the wiki link for Catalan Numbers for my dissertation and can not find a way of finding rho from scratch, using other results etc. In doing this I have spiralled into a hole

Comment: The result you showed me, I don't really understand either, nor entirely how to get there

Comment: @Luke I suggest you search the Internet for "proof of integral representation of Catalan numbers" and you'll find links to several related papers. You can also find more information on Catalan numbers at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html.